# Trigger for Case's Subject but change of Owner To Queue Not happening

Tags: apex, trigger, case, email2case

At a conceptual level,  below  is what  Trigger code is doing

1. Query for Salesforce queue name Prepaid
2. Iterate over the Email 2 Case records for Record Type as "Executive Response " I get (from Trigger.new)
3. Calls .contains() on the Case's Subject to see if  target word "Airtel" exists
4. Update the OwnerId to  queue

```
trigger PrepaidEmailSubjectAsw on Case (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
        List<Group> lstPre = [SELECT Id from Group where Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperNAME = 'Prepaid'  LIMIT 1];
        if(!lstPre.isEmpty()){
            for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
                if(c.Subject != Null && c.Subject.Contains('Airtel') == True && c.RecordType.Name == 'Executive Response'){
                    c.ownerId = lstPre[0].Id;
                }
            }

            update lstPre;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is , I don't see the Case owner got changed to queue as Prepaid, can you suggest what mistake is there

Comment: Why is this code posted under a different user name on the Developer Forums? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000UeY4QAK

Comment: yeah i think i asked in one of my college groups  ,i think she posted it,not sure

Comment: I find that rather difficult to believe, given that you and that user have a long history of posting identical or nearly-identical content. I also find it interesting that both you and that other user have profile photos that appear to be stolen from other sources.

Comment: It's not against the rules to post under an assumed name, but it's very much against the rules to steal content (including question content and photos) from someone else.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to reconsider some of these aspects of your participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from `Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete` being wrong (it should be `Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert`), this is something that requires basic debugging skills. You need to look at your code, and determine what circumstances could lead to the result you're seeing.

As an example:

- The first thing you should check is whether or not your query is returning any records. You are, after all, saying "skip this code if we didn't find our target Queue". So if you didn't find the queue, you'd obviously not execute the rest of the code.
- The next thing you should check is your `Case` Subject. Does it actually contain the string you're looking for? Does the word use the same casing (i.e. is it "Airtel", or is it "AIRTEL", "airtel", or "extrairtel"?). You might need to use `containsIgnoreCase()` instead, or add whitespace before and after your target string.

Aside from your mistake in checking the trigger context, I suspect that the issue is with `c.RecordType.Name == 'Executive Response'`.

Any field that requires more than one dot/period/full stop to access means that you're trying to look at *related data* instead of data contained on the record itself. Trigger context variables do not contain related data. If you need related data in a trigger, then you need to query for it. As a brief aside, `c.Subject.contains()` is ok because the field itself (`c.Subject`) only required one dot. The `.contains()` is calling a method instead of trying to get data from a child or parent record (as `c.RecordType.Name` is trying to do).

In this case though, you could avoid the extra query (queries are our most precious resource) and just do a comparison against `c.RecordTypeId`. You can get your target Record Type's Id (using the same record type name that you're using now) through the SObject describe information.

```
// Schema.SObjectType.<SObject API name here> gives you a DescribeSObjectResult, which 
//   contains methods like...
// getRecordTypeInfosByName(), which gives you a map keyed on the record type label
// and the value of the map is a RecordTypeInfo, where you can finally get the
//   id from
Id targetRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Executive Response').getRecordTypeId();
```

You'd want to have that line of code outside of your loop.

#### Other notes

- `<boolean value> == true` can always be replaced with simply `<boolean value>`. This applies to `c.Subject.Contains('Airtel')`. You do not need the `== true` after it
- You don't need to `update lstPre;`. You aren't making any changes to the queue. If you don't have a trigger, workflow, process builder, or flow on the `Group` object, then this statement is just wasting a little bit of your limits

Answer (score 0):

When you create a case from the Cases tab, you are automatically listed as the case owner, unless the assignment rule checkbox is displayed and you select it to enable the assignment rule. If it’s selected by default, you can override the assignment rule and assign yourself as the owner by deselecting the checkbox.

So to summarize you can achieve this using case assignment rules instead of writing a trigger.